# Amend wordpress password function

Tags: posts, filters

I simply want to add a H2 or whatever html tag above the content in this password protection function. Is this correct?

```
function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<h2><br>Password Protected Area</h2><form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
    ' . __( "This content is password protected. If you are media requiring access please contact our Press Office,  press@djawards.com and they will be happy to assist you." ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Why to edit the whole form ? Filters are good because they gives you the current output and you just need to add your string to it then return it back to WordPress.

In above example you are not using it so let use it.

Example:-

```
add_filter('the_password_form', function( $form ){
    $my_html = '<h2><br>Password Protected Area</h2>';
    return $my_html . $form;
});
```